# Argument type System.Linq.IQueryable<> is not assignable to parameter type Systems.collection.generic.ienumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to concatenate two fields from a table and assign it as a list. Please see code below

```
public List<ForDropDownList> GetAccountsForDownList()
{
    var accountList = new List<ForDropDownList>();

    using (_context = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        accountList.AddRange( _context.Account
                                      .Select(a => new
                                      {
                                          a.AccountId, 
                                          FullName = string.Concat(a.FirstName, a.LastName)
                                      }));
    }

    return accountList;
}
```

This is my model

```
public class ForDropDownList
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error:

> Argument type System.Linq.IQueryable<{AccountId:int, FullName:string}> is not assignable to parameter type Systems.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Your Select instanciates a new dynamic object which then you cannot add to your `List<ForDropDownList>`
The following code Should work:

```
accountList.AddRange(_context.Account.Select(a => new ForDropDownList { AccountId = a.AccountId, FullName = string.Concat(a.FirstName, a.LastName) }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use the strong type instead of the "new {}" anonymous type. For example:

```
accountList.AddRange(_context.Account.Select(a => new ForDropDownList { AccountId = a.AccountId, FullName = string.Concat(a.FirstName, a.LastName) }));
```

C# cann't convert the anonymous type to the strong type.
FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your projection like below and call `ToList` at the end:

```
_context.Account
        .Select(a => new ForDropDownList
        {
            a.AccountId, 
            FullName = string.Concat(a.FirstName, a.LastName)
        }).ToList()
```

These changes are needed because:

- Without specifying `ForDropDownList` the projection we do create instances of an anonymous type with the same properties as `ForDropDownList`. Since the type of the object we project is not `ForDropDownList`, we add the resulted collection to a collection of `ForDropDownList` objects (`AddRange`...)
- The `ToList()` is needed to force the execution of the query and get the results in memory. The `AddRange` expects a collection. On the other hand you have just defined the query, you didn't request its execution. So as it was it couldn't be used as an argument for `AddRange` method.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for this one. Now I have a different approach to doing this.

Comment: @stackquestions You are welcome. I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: @stackquestions just a question, Didn't you need the `ToList` at the end?